# Bluetooth not available after installing Ubuntu on RPi 4

Tags: bluetooth, raspberrypi, 21.04

Just installed Ubuntu on to my Raspberry Pi 4 (8GB). But I hate wires, so I want to connect my BT keyboard and mouse. However I get the [Please plug in dongle] message when I open by BT settings.

I have also tried updating the software and firmware as well as commands such as

`sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`
`service bluetooth restart`

when I run

`service bluetooth service`

I get

````
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-09-10 17:22:56 BST; 36min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1155 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8964)
     Memory: 1.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1155 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 10 17:22:56 rob-R****1 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Sep 10 17:22:56 rob-R****1 bluetoothd[1155]: Bluetooth daemon 5.56
Sep 10 17:22:56 rob-R****1 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Sep 10 17:22:56 rob-R****1 bluetoothd[1155]: Starting SDP server
Sep 10 17:22:57 rob-R****1 bluetoothd[1155]: Bluetooth management interface 1.19 initialized```

I've also noticed that a log of the config files are empty? Is this normal? I only figured this out when I overclocked the CPU.
````

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comment because lack of reputation, so I'm forced to add this comment as an answer. I have Raspberry Pi 4 8GB and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop and there is no way to enable Bluetooth. How can I report this issue?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1225955)

Answer (score 0):

On 22.04 you need `sudo apt install pi-bluetooth` and disable the serial uart that interferes with the bluetooth interface:

Edit `/boot/firmware/config.txt` and set `enable_uart=0` or run `sudo pibootctl set serial.enabled=off`

For some reason 22.04 removes the `btcmd.txt` that's included in other distributions, so make sure your `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt` includes the following settings: `net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc`